# Poor image quality on Android through Unity Remote

Tags: android, unity, graphics

I have started to work on the company's latest project using Unity3D and the workflow is just awesome.

The problem is when running the game on a real Android device (using Unity Remote) the image quality is very poor in comparison to how it looks in the editor:

[image: How it looks.]
(Click for a full view. Look at those sprite edges.)

Is this...

- caused by the phone's limited graphics capabilities
- or have I configured the project improperly
- or is it Unity Remote and actually building it for Android will fix the quality? (Based on Unity Answers site, Unity Remote is the cause : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/408896/android-image-quality-is-poor-compared-to-the-qual.html#comment-408945)

Comment: Maybe you could inform us about the Android phone you use, so we could answer to the first question!

Comment: LG Optimus L7, not quite fancy but It works just fine on simple games like this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've answered your own question. Yes, Unity remote compresses the hell out of your game and sends screenshots to the phone. It looks entirely different with an actual build. (an  installed .apk)